# GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this) not respond

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have an android applcation and I added Google Analytics Tracker to it and it works (I can see the views in the Analytics panel).

The problem is that sometime the application starts to load and then gets stuck and not responds anymore. I tried to debug it and I found out that when it comes to the line

```
  GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

sometime there is no respond.

Why is this happen and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I added optional analytics_global_config and it still happens

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
     android:resource="@xml/analytics_global_config" />
```

**analytics_global_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <string name="ga_appName">HebConvertor</string>
     <string name="ga_appVersion">1.0</string>
     <string name="ga_logLevel">verbose</string>
     <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">1000</integer>
     <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
 </resources>
```

---

**MyApplication:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application  {

      // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
      private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "XX-XXXXXXXX-X";

      public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
      }

      HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

      public MyApplication() {    
        super();
      }

      synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
            if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

              GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
              Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                      : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                      : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
              mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
            }
            return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
      }
}
```

**app_tracker.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
    <!-- tools:ignore="TypographyDashes" -->
    <!-- The apps Analytics Tracking Id -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">XX-XXXXXXXX-X</string>

    <!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- catch and report uncaught exceptions from the app -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

    <!-- If ga_autoActivityTracking is enabled, an alternate screen name can be specified to
    substitute for the full length canonical Activity name in screen view hit. In order to
    specify an alternate screen name use an <screenName> element, with the name attribute
    specifying the canonical name, and the value the alias to use instead. -->
    <screenName name="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
            }
            getOverflowMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
            GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            //Stop the analytics tracking
            GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
        }

        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            protected  InterstitialAd interstitial;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

               // Get tracker.
               Tracker t = ((MyApplication)getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
               // Set screen name.
               t.setScreenName("MainActivity");

            ...
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an optional global configuration (specified in the manifest), see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html).

Comment: @stkent I added it and it still happens

Comment: Anything relevant at the warn/error levels in the logcat?

Comment: @stkent - no,  nothing

Comment: Just found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423218/android-googleanalytics-getinstance

Comment: @stkent how do I rollback/install this version?

Comment: Play Services version is specified in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I use eclipse  . in version.xml I have  <integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer>

Comment: Try `6171000` for version 6.1.71.

Comment: App crashes... version.xml is in google_play_services project

Comment: That number must be generated then. I don't use Eclipse, so I don't know where else you need to look to specify the version number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Google Play Services 6.5. See [Android GoogleAnalytics getInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423218/android-googleanalytics-getinstance) for details.

**The issue is fixed in Google Play Services 7.0** that was releases on 2015, March 19th.
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

If you must use Play Services 6.5, the workaround is to either configure Google Analytics from code instead of xml or downgrade to Google Play Services 6.1.

The following code when added to your Application class is equivalent to your manifest configuration:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application  {
  //...
  private Tracker mTracker;
  public synchronized Tracker getAppTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this)
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker("XX-XXXXXXXX-X"); // Replace with your real tracker id
      mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
      mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
      mTracker.setSessionTimeout(-1);

      // mTracker.setSampleRate(100.0d); // Not needed. The default sampling rate it 100%
    }
    return mTracker; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Downgrade to Google Play Services 6.1 was the only thing that helped.

Comment: And here is another long discuss about the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=82157