# How to do a rollback from google-play-services in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have problems with google play services 6.5.87 and I need to rollback/install version 6.1 ( 6.1.71 or 6.1.11). How do I do that? Where can I get the files? In thh Android SDK I can't see any option for that. I use Eclipse.

I found a file version.xml in google-play-services_lib project

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <resources>
     <integer name="google_play_services_version">6587000</integer> 
 </resources>
```

Comment: You should really just use Gradle. You can use Gradle with Eclipse. Just setup through the Eclipse configurations or run via command line; however Android Studio will do this all for you. You can import your project into Android Studio from Eclipse and just set the Google Play Services version. This whole process will take around 10 mins.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Can I go back to eclipse after that? If I use eclipse configurations / command line (without android studio) - what do I need to do? I never used gradle

Comment: You could also post a question about what issue you're having and we could help you fix the issue...

Comment: this is my original issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670303/googleanalytics-getinstancethis-not-respond

Comment: @TamarG Yes. I used to us Eclipse + Gradle. It may just be easier for you to use Android Studio, File -> Import Project from Eclipse. It will try and setup Gradle for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot roll back by just changing the integer, you need to specify the build you are actually using.

If you are building the google play services project, you would use this line in your manifest so that the build number is generated dynamically.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

That being said, you still need to make sure the version you are building is an version older than the one you are having problems with.

Here is a good article on how to build using a project:
http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/

However, if you are copying a previously built library, then you must reference the correct library in the properties of your project. Please check your settings for Eclipse / Android Studio to make sure you have added the older library. You should still use the dynamic value for the integer in your manifest, but if you insist on using a static value, you can find the integer value of the library in *google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml*

Comment: where can I find an older version? Is there any way to downgrade through SDK?

Comment: You can download older versions from previous SDKs using the "Android SDK Manager" http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to download the latest "Google Repository" via the SDK Manager. Add ${android_sdk}/extras/google/m2repository/ to your list of repositories to pull dependencies from (See "Declaring Repositories" [in this](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/usage.html)). Then put your old version number back in your maven dependency declaration. (This would be if you pulled the Google Play services dependency via [Maven/Ant declarations](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/dependencies.html).)

You could also obviously copy the aar file out of the m2repository directory, but then you have to manually manage the dependencies and deal with class not found exceptions.