# White screen hangs with google analytics android

Tags: java, android, xml, google-analytics

I am trying to implement analytics into my app but when I put the following into AndroidManifest.xml the app stays on a white screen

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

Also, I cannot send dispatches when I create it programatically, if I use `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this.getBaseContext()).dispatchLocalHits();` the logical shows this and does not dispatch: `V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.`
Thanks! :D

Comment: What version of GA are you using? I had similar problem after update to `6.5.87`, so I still use `6.1.71`.

Comment: I'm using the latest so I'll try older ones thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a know Analytics bug in Google Play 6.5 that will hand the app on `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context)`. Please see this response for details on how to workaround the bug: [GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this) not respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670303/googleanalytics-getinstancethis-not-respond/27678101#27678101)

**The issue is fixed in Google Play Services 7.0** that was released in March 19, 2015. Upgrading to 7.0 fixes the deadlock.