# Android app sometimes' doesn't launch

Tags: android

I'm having a strange problem with a native android app of mine (java).
Sometimes it crashes on the splash screen. It happens 8 time in 10. 
The strange thing is, it doesn't happen on some smartphones, but on others it does.
The logs don't show an error or warning.

The only thing I have found is this info-warning :
W/ResourceType﹕ Found multiple library tables, ignoring..

I've been searching for days now, and still have no clue.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: For reference: This bug was fixed by updating the Google Play Services from 6.5 to a higher version. The fix was found by using the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670303/googleanalytics-getinstancethis-not-respond) question.