# Android play services 6.5.87 force stop

Tags: android, google-analytics

If I use google analytics in my app and have it killed (force stop) the next time it starts `GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);` blocks forever. It does not happen with 6.1.71.

Is there something known about it? Something to prevent this?

Comment: Did you check if device supports at least 6.5.87 play services? also: Where is stacktrace(logcat's logs)?

Comment: Are you saying that you are force-stopping Play Services from the Settings app? And, if so, why would you expect Play Services to work after that?

Comment: This is a known problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533679/google-analytics-blocks-android-app/27542483#27542483 . Comments on that question link to google issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android GoogleAnalytics getInstance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423218/android-googleanalytics-getinstance)